# background position not working on a parent with 100% width and height?

Tags: html, css

so I am trying to move a child div with background image but background position no matter how much i set isn't moving, this is my code in html:

```
<div className="review-dots-container">
  <div className="review-dots-purple" />
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.review-dots-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  .review-dots-purple {
    background-image: url('./scss/img/dots-purple@1x.png');
    height: 368.08px;
    width: 368.12px;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 70% 80%;
    @include mediaQuery(768px) {     
      height: 368.08px;
      width: 112px;
    }
  }
}
```

so the parent has inherit the width and height, it's positioned to relative with the child div with background image positioned to absolute, but the image is not moving anywhere no matter how much i set, even if it's

```
background-position: 120% 180%;
```

Comment: first you cannot have more than 100% on the background-position, then if you background is set to auto size, all the background-position % values are equivalent. change the background-size and see what happen

Comment: @TemaniAfif changed it from 1% to 100%, still, the child with background image not moving anywhere, i was expecting it to move since it's parent container has larger width and height,

Comment: from 1% to 100% all the background-position are equivalent if the size is 100%, so check the size of the background ... change the background-size to see the effect

Comment: @TemaniAfif i was setting the width and height from the child cause it's how i want the image sized, so you are suggesting i cropped the image to the size i want to move it? then the height and width with it, is for the space to move for background position?

Comment: I am explaining you how the background-position works with % values :) ... If the background-image is set to 100% width of its container ALL the values used in % are the same, you can put any value you won't see any difference ... so to see a difference you need to change the background-size or use px value instead of %

Comment: i don't know why but using pixels worked, while percentage didn't.

Comment: check the dup and this : https://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/